# Is there a maximal ideal that isn't prime if the ring is non commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, examples-counterexamples

In the proof of "every maximal ideal is prime" we use commutativity at some point. So I was wondering if there were examples of non abelian rings with a maximal (one-sided) ideal that isn't prime...

Comment: Note that for non-commutative rings you need, first of all, to distinguish between left, right or two-sided ideals. If every definition is made consistently, I would guess that, at least for two-sided ideals, it should still be true. But it is just a guess.

Comment: Yes I think it is true for two sided ideals

Comment: For a field $k$ and $n > 1$, the matrix ring $M_n(k)$ is not commutative and has only two two-sided ideals. So $\{0\}$ is a maximal two-sided ideal that isn't prime (because the ring has zero divisors).

Comment: How is $\{0\}$ a maximal ideal?

Comment: Oh because you can only compare two-sided to two-sided, left to left and right to right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, $M_2(F)$, where $F$ is a field, the zero ideal is a maximal ideal which does not satisfy the commutative definition of a prime ideal.

However, that is kind of a cheat because prime ideals are defined differently for noncommutative rings: an ideal $P$ is called prime if for any two ideals $A,B$, $AB\subseteq P$ implies $A\subseteq P$ or $B\subseteq P$.

So the "right" version of this question asks if maximal ideals are prime with respect to this definition. The general definition reduces to the "commutative definition" in commutative rings, and using this definition, maximal ideals *are* prime ideals in noncommutative rings.

So while I guess you did not know what waters you were wading into when you asked the question, I think this latter explanation is the one you should prefer.

You also mentioned the possibility of prime one-sided ideals. Then again you'll have to pick which definition you want to discuss, for there are many variants on what constitutes a one-sided prime ideal.